# Create pod that relies on external library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Is it possible to create a pod that requires an external third party library (shipped as libXY.a) without including a copy of it in the pod itself? The problem is, that I can't include the library files themselves, for copyright reasons. Basically anyone using the pod would have to somehow include their own copy of that library in their project.

Is something like this possible?

PS. The pod would be a wrapper around this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if a copy of libXY.a is hosted somewhere, for example in a zip file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  // …other spec settings…
  s.source = { :http => "http://downloads.xy.com/XY-version.zip" }
  s.source_files= 'XY-version/*.h'
  s.preserve_paths = 'XY-version/libXY.a'
  s.xcconfig = { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/XYPodName/XY-version"' }
  s.libraries = 'XY'
end
```

(Suggestions welcome; I didn't know about `vendored_libraries`, maybe I should use that?)

Comment: This wouldn't work though as he says he can't include the lib, it would have to be obtained else where...?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a development Pod, but unless the `podspec` can be linted (`pod spec lint`) it would not be allowed to go into the pod repo. You could of course get around this with an empty libXY.a implementation.

If you wanted to go down the development pod route you could place the libXY.a somewhere say in folder A, creating a pod spec for it, say the pod had the name `Internal`.
In you `Podfile` for your project you would then reference this local spec:

```
pod 'Internal', :path => '<path to folder A>'
```

When running `pod install` it sees this is a local pod and places it in a "Development Pods" folder (not that that is really important!)

You want to add any `lib*.a` files as [`vendored_libraries`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_libraries).